# Azure Search Provider does not index any template fields

Tags: content-search, azure-search

The azure search based Sitecore instance deployed as App service does not index any fields defined in the template. I dumped the key:value from searchresult object's Fields and we got the following keys (but the same dump from solr based local instance has all fields indexed)

```
azureuniqueid : c2l0ZWNvcmU6Ly93ZWIvezcyRjJCQzIwLTgzREQtNDJEMi1BM0Q3LUQyOTBGNjQ1OEZDMn0_bGFuZz1lbiZ2ZXI9MQ== 
boost_2 : 1 
boost 2 : 1 
__bucketable : False 
compat_prefix
___bucketable_b : False 
__created_by : sitecore\maria 
compat_prefix___created_by_s : sitecore\maria 
compat_prefix___created_by_s_t_en : sitecore\maria 
__enable_item_fallback : False 
compat_prefix___enable_item_fallback_b : False 
__is_bucket : False 
compat_prefix___is_bucket_b : False 
_name : OCT Article 19 
compat_prefix__name_s : OCT Article 19 
name : OCT Article 19 
_parent : 90bf52f8151145d08d6adff885eabb3c 
compat_prefix__parent_s : 90bf52f8151145d08d6adff885eabb3c 
parent : 90bf52f8151145d08d6adff885eabb3c 
_version : 1 
compat_prefix__version_i : 1 
creator_1 : sitecore\maria 
creator 1 : sitecore\maria 
culture : en 
database_1 : web 
database 1 : web 
databasename : web 
datasource_1 : sitecore 
datasource 1 : sitecore 
datasource : sitecore 
fullpath_1 : /sitecore/content/fedpartnership/home/pages/newsandevents/oct article 19 
fullpath 1 : /sitecore/content/fedpartnership/home/pages/newsandevents/oct article 19 
path : /sitecore/content/fedpartnership/home/pages/newsandevents/oct article 19 
group_1 : 72f2bc2083dd42d2a3d7d290f6458fc2 
group 1 : 72f2bc2083dd42d2a3d7d290f6458fc2 
itemid : 72f2bc2083dd42d2a3d7d290f6458fc2 
haschildren : False 
haschildren_b : False 
hidden_2 : False 
hidden 2 : False 
id_1 : 72f2bc2083dd42d2a3d7d290f6458fc2 
id 1 : 72f2bc2083dd42d2a3d7d290f6458fc2 
indexname_1 : sitecore_web_index 
indexname 1 : sitecore_web_index 
isbucket_text : 0 
isbucket text : 0 
istemplate : False 
istemplate_b : False 
language_1 : en 
language 1 : en 
language : en 
latestversion_1 : True 
latestversion 1 : True 
lock : False 
lock_b : False 
parsedcreatedby : sitecoremaria 
createdby : sitecoremaria 
parsedlanguage : english 
parsedupdatedby : sitecoremaria 
updatedby : sitecoremaria 
path_1 : 11111111111111111111111111111111|0de95ae441ab4d019eb067441b7c2450|edd8c631d95b49a0b2a750a1deff4303|862a1f484d46416aa311b2f9e47d1e90|b4712aa42198458685e5209ca8ae2086|90bf52f8151145d08d6adff885eabb3c|72f2bc2083dd42d2a3d7d290f6458fc2 
path 1 : 11111111111111111111111111111111|0de95ae441ab4d019eb067441b7c2450|edd8c631d95b49a0b2a750a1deff4303|862a1f484d46416aa311b2f9e47d1e90|b4712aa42198458685e5209ca8ae2086|90bf52f8151145d08d6adff885eabb3c|72f2bc2083dd42d2a3d7d290f6458fc2 
paths : 11111111111111111111111111111111|0de95ae441ab4d019eb067441b7c2450|edd8c631d95b49a0b2a750a1deff4303|862a1f484d46416aa311b2f9e47d1e90|b4712aa42198458685e5209ca8ae2086|90bf52f8151145d08d6adff885eabb3c|72f2bc2083dd42d2a3d7d290f6458fc2 
site : login|admin|service|fedpartnership|scheduler|system|publisher sites : login|admin|service|fedpartnership|scheduler|system|publisher smallcreateddate_2 : 10/19/2023 16:59:28 smallcreateddate 2 : 10/19/2023 16:59:28 
createddate : 10/19/2023 16:59:28 
smallupdateddate_2 : 10/24/2023 14:52:01 
smallupdateddate 2 : 10/24/2023 14:52:01 
updated : 10/24/2023 14:52:01 
template_1 : 15d6b28769814dec915e8e932f8b6164 
template 1 : 15d6b28769814dec915e8e932f8b6164 
templateid : 15d6b28769814dec915e8e932f8b6164 
templatename_1 : ArticlePage 
templatename 1 : ArticlePage 
templatename : ArticlePage 
uniqueid_1 : sitecore://web/{72f2bc20-83dd-42d2-a3d7-d290f6458fc2}?lang=en&ver=1 
uniqueid 1 : sitecore://web/{72f2bc20-83dd-42d2-a3d7-d290f6458fc2}?lang=en&ver=1 
uri : sitecore://web/{72f2bc20-83dd-42d2-a3d7-d290f6458fc2}?lang=en&ver=1 
urllink : /en/fedpartnership/home/Pages/NewsAndEvents/OCT-Article-19 
url : /en/fedpartnership/home/Pages/NewsAndEvents/OCT-Article-19
```

part of the keys from Solr based dump:

```
_indexname : sitecore_web_index 
authors : fe8bcf1525b04ae7bafb25e120a9d9ff 
authors_sm : fe8bcf1525b04ae7bafb25e120a9d9ff 
__enforce_version_presence : False 
__enforce_version_presence_b : False 
showfacebooksharebutton : True 
showfacebooksharebutton_b : True 
_templatename : ArticlePage 
templatename : ArticlePage 
isbucket_text : 0 
isbucket_text_s : 0 
parsedcreatedby : sitecoreadmin 
parsedcreatedby_s : sitecoreadmin 
createdby : sitecoreadmin 
_datasource : sitecore 
datasource : sitecore 
parsedupdatedby : sitecoreadmin 
parsedupdatedby_s : sitecoreadmin 
updatedby : sitecoreadmin 
noindex : False 
noindex_b : False 
__smallupdateddate : 10/6/2023 4:11:30 AM 
__smallupdateddate_tdt : 10/6/2023 4:11:30 AM 
updated : 10/6/2023 4:11:30 AM 
_group : 64e8215236414c28ad07d7cabe17397a 
itemid : 64e8215236414c28ad07d7cabe17397a 
culture : en 
culture_s : en 
_template : 15d6b28769814dec915e8e932f8b6164 
templateid : 15d6b28769814dec915e8e932f8b6164 
og_image_width : 0 
og_image_width_tf : 0 
__content_test : 00000000000000000000000000000000 
__content_test_sm : 00000000000000000000000000000000 
herotitle : H ArticlePage12 
herotitle_t : H ArticlePage12 
_uniqueid : sitecore://web/{64e82152-3641-4c28-ad07-d7cabe17397a}?lang=en&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_web_index 
uri : sitecore://web/{64e82152-3641-4c28-ad07-d7cabe17397a}?lang=en&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_web_index 
title : ArticlePage 12 
title_t_en : ArticlePage 12 
heroimage : Header image block 
heroimage_t_en : Header image block 
_name : ArticlePage12 
name : ArticlePage12 
__created_by : sitecore\Admin 
__created_by_s : sitecore\Admin 
_database : web databasename : web 
title_t : ArticlePage 12 
conclusiontitle : Conclusion 
conclusiontitle_t : Conclusion 
parsedlanguage : english 
...
```

can anyone help me understand how to make the Azure search based Sitecore index all those fields?

Comment: Check `<defaultCloudIndexConfiguration` in `showconfig.aspx`. Is `IndexAllFields` set to true? Are some fields included or excluded?